# Delete every other rows except the rows number in a given list

Tags: mysql, database, delete-row, large-data-volumes

so basically here's what I want to do: I have an account table, I have a list of acct_id: (3, 24, 515, 6326, 17), assuming I have about 100,000 accounts in the table, what's the most effective way to delete all the other rows besides the one with the account_id in my given list?

I came up with something like:

```
delete from account where acct_id is not in (3, 24, 515, 6326, 17);
```

I heard this query is slow because it's recursive or something. consider the number of rows I have, that would be *very slow*. what's a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have table relationships - foreign keys from other tables to this one?
How many indexes do you (plan to) have on that table?
These can change the answer dramatically: i.e. dropping a table might not be the option, or simple DELETE performance would be same as in tricky ways.
Know what you're optimizing: it might be not broken.

Comment: @fei I know this question is old, but may I know why or where you heard that query of yours is slow?

Answer (score 4):

```
delete from table
 where not acct_id in (3, 24, 515, 6326, etc.);
```

Depending on the database flavor, indexes, distributed or not, etc., this could be a lot of work.  The alternative which works efficiently even in fully-journaled databases is:

```
create table2 temp as /* create new table from the rows to keep */
   select *
   from table
   where acct_id in (3, 24, 515, 6326, etc.);
drop table;           /* discard table */
create table as       /* copy new table to rename */
  select * from table2;
drop table2;          /* get rid of temporary table */
```

Comment: that seems almost the same as the solution i came up with...care to explain a little more how this is effective on a large volumes of data?

Comment: I didn't see the SQL statement when I wrote the answer.  Did you add that later?

Comment: i didn't put it in a code tag earlier. but the alternative you suggested seems promising. thx.

Comment: As he's using MySQL the last step can be `RENAME TABLE table2 TO table;`

Comment: Beware of the side effects of dropping tables:  index will need to be recreated and other constraints.  I prefer to use TRUNCATE TABLE.  Posted a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems fine to me, but take a look at [`Explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) if you are trying to optimize your queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have got an index on acct_id I cannot see any reason why your query should be slow.
As far as I know

```
in (3, 24, 515, 6326, 17)
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
acct_id != 3 AND acct_id != 24 ...
```

which should be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to MySQL, but deletes in general are relatively expensive because they require the engine to do a bunch of selects to make sure it is deleting the right records as well as the actual deletes. You also wind up with a lot of transactions added to the transaction logs (depending on engine and settings of course).

If you only have a small set of records you want to keep and a large set you want to throw out, then you can get much fast performance by cheating...

You copy the records you want to keep and either drop or truncate the table, then add the "keepers" back in.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to avoid DELETE and use TRUNCATE table because when you delete the database does two operations.  delete and write  records into rollback segments.

Of course, this means there is no rollback when you are truncating.

```
-- copy the few records into a temp table
select into temp 
 select * from account
 where acct_id in (3, 24, 515, 6326, 17);

-- truncate is super fast
truncate table account;

-- put back the few records
insert into account select * from temp;

drop table temp;
```